# Inline Html Styling appearing differently on different email clients

Tags: c#, html, css, email

```
    string tableStyle = " style='box-shadow:11px 13px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);font-family:Helvetica;background:#fff;border: 3px solid black;font-size:16px;width: 100%;' ";


        string EmailHtml = @"<html><section class='content-header'>
        <h3 style='font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 26px;color:purple;'>HEADING 1</h3>
       </section>
       <section class='content'>
           <div class='row'>
                    <div class='box box-primary'>
                    <div class='box-body' style='padding:50px;background-color:white;width:50%;border-radius:20px;'>
                    <table role='grid' cellspacing='0px' cellpadding='3px' " + tableStyle + "" + @" </table>
```

This is just a sample of the code. Some styling gets lost on different email clients, is what I am doing wrong or what is the best workaround for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which styles go missing? I imagine box-shadow might on certain email clients - not all email clients support all CSS see... You are correctly using inline styles though.

Comment: Here's a great reference by mailchimp that shows current email client support. http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

Comment: The width of 100% , box-shadow and the cell spacing.

Comment: Thanks @Manatarms il have a look